# How to fix "App not installed" error for PhoneGap Build app?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I used phoneGap Build to build an Android app; however, I am currently facing a problem. Whenever I update the code, rebuild the app, and try to install it on my Android device, I get "App not Installed" error. If completely delete the app and reinstall it, it works fine. But I don't want my user to delete the app and reinstall it to get the update(this is very unprofessional)

I tried to change the versionCode and versionName, but nothing worked.

here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.orcatheapp.orca" version="2.0.4"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
  <name>Orca</name>
  <description>
        Let The Killer Whale Kill Boredom...
  </description>
  <author email="omarkhalil.m17@gmail.com" href="omarkhalil.m17@gmail.com">
      Omar and Zeyad
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />

<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <icon src="www/img/1.png" platform="android" width="57" height="57" density="mdpi" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to your app id, for example com.orcatheapp.orca in this line:

```
<widget id="com.orcatheapp.orca" version="2.0.4"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

When you have a new version on PlayStore your users can download automatically from GooglePlay or PlayStore, remmember change the id version in this example: `version="2.0.5"`